# ASP.NET GridView Access Cell By Name

Tags: asp.net

I want to access a certain cell in a row of a datagrid by name instead of index just in case the columns get reordered(Which has happened already)

MyBox.Text = ListAllCategories.Rows[ListAllCategories.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;

Instead of using "Cells[1]", I want to do something like "Cells["Name"]"(Which didn't work) or something similar where "Name" is the name of the column inside the GridView.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use indexes they fail when more columns are created.

Instead use MyGrid.FindControl("NameOfYourControl").

For example assume there is a label called lblID, a grid view called gvMyGridView.

Try this:

```
Dim l as Label
l = Me.gvMyGridView.FindControl("lblID")
You can also use CType to cast it or get the text contents of this label, etc.
```

Comment: This will work if you're using TemplateFields and not standard BoundFields, and you're using named controls to bind the data to.

Comment: Why would you ever want t o use bound fields?  They are more trouble then they are worth.  I will never use BoundFields...they limit you on functionality and what you can do in a column.

Comment: Even the link you gave mentioned this:

"I'd do it so that I'd use TemplateField's with Literals or Labels, and use FindControl to locate them on specific row, so that column ordering doesn't matter. It's eases up things, when placing needs to be changed (doesn't impact code at all)."

Comment: @jonh - boundfields are super easy to wire up and reduce complexity when none is needed. true they are limited in their power, but when it comes to wiring up and binding a quick gridview, they come in quite handy. also, pulling data from boundfields is WAY easier than with template fields. not to say template fields aren't great in their own right, but don't push aside boundfields simply because they are limited in power

Comment: Um.. I just saw the notes it looks like you took my comment as a negative.  I want to clarify that I think your idea as a GOOD idea, not a bad one.  I was just saying that this would work so long as you're using TemplateFields, because you didn't specifically mention them.  I was just adding what I perceived of as missing information to an already good answer.